# Core Data renamed causes failure to load NSManagedObjectModel

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm creating a new version of an App that's live. I don't wish to keep any of the existing Core Data data or model so I thought the simplest way to do this would be to side-step the existing data and create a new, differently names store. I changed the name of the file `MyApp.xcdatamodeld` to `MyAppV2.xcdatamodeld` and the line

`let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp")`

to

`let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyAppV2")`

Now, when I run, I get the following error: `Failed to load NSManagedObjectModel with URL 'file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../MyApp.app/MyAppV2.momd/'`

I'm using iOS 10.

Am I going about this the wrong way or is there something else I need to change?

Many thanks.

Comment: are you set the model version from xcode.?

Comment: I don't think so. How would I do that? Do I need to? I don't wish to migrate anything from the old app. This is a complete rewrite from the iOS empty project template with Core Data.

Comment: Is the model file included in the project?  did you check the build stages to see that it is copied? are you using a framework - if so the model is not in the main bundle which is where NSPersistentContainer looks.  You can try removing it from the project and adding it back, or passing in a pointer to the model manually.

Comment: I tried everything in order (except passing a pointer to the model manually — how do you do that?) but removing it an adding it back seems to have fixed it! Thanks very much. Is there some way I can accept this comment as an accepted answer? I'm not sure what the stack overflow etiquette is in this circumstance. Thanks again.

Comment: Assuming the Model exists in the main bundle (build and check the artefact) and there is no misspelling, clear the project and derived data and delete the previous version from device/simulator.

Comment: @shallowThought I had tried that (many times!), but Jon Rose's suggestion already solved it.

Comment: @JoshParadroid Ah, sorry. Missed that.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is not to rename anything. Just change the model to what you want and any existing databases will be incompatible and so should get blown away the first time the user runs the new version of your app.

If you want to rename anyway then the best bet is to remove the old store from your app completely and then add a new one with the new name. The `MyApp.xcdatamodeld` is not actually a file but a package containing a few nested folders and files so it's not going to rename easily.

Comment: Core Data doesn't automatically blow away the existing data, you have to write code to do that when you detect that the models don't match.

Comment: Should doesn't mean automatically. And you need that code anyway, there is no other recovery for a user with an corrupt or otherwise incompatible DB.

Comment: In that context your answer makes more sense. I'll reverse my down vote. I wonder if it would be helpful to include some example code of detecting the mismatch and deleting the DB?